# Django CACHEOPS different timeout for different querysets

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-redis

I'm using Django CACHEOPS.  [cacheops' README](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops)

In settings.py how can I config different timeouts for different querysets?

(cache the `get` queryset for 10 seconds and cache `queryset fetches` for 60 seconds)

Something like this: (This obviously has duplication key error)

```
CACHEOPS = {
    'blog.Article': {'ops': 'fetch', 'timeout': 60},
    'blog.Article': {'ops': 'get', 'timeout': 10},
}
```

My goal is: I want to cache each article detail page longer than the article list page.

Answer (score 0):

As you see a key in `CACHEOPS` definition is for models, not for queryset

`blog.Article` is a `Article` model in a `blog` application,
not a queryset.

Then knowing the above you have only workarounds for a glitch in the cacheops and it would be

```
CACHEOPS_DEFAULTS = {
    'timeout': 60         # first level - a default
}

CACHEOPS = {
    'blog.*': {'ops': 'fetch', 'timeout': 60},  # second level - a default per application
    'blog.Article': {'ops': 'get', 'timeout': 10},
}
```

Rather use decorator to cover specific `get` on a specific model:

```
from cacheops import cached_as
@cached_as(Article, timeout=10)
def get_cached_article(...
     Article.objects. ... your queryset
     ...
```